# Selenium script fails when remote desktop connection is stopped (AWS Server)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run some basic python selenium script on my virtual windows machine (AWS EC2 instance) that I connect to through Remote Desktop Connection. The script is supposed to run constantly for a couple of days. I run it directly from the interpreter I installed there. It runs fine until I close the remote connection. For the period when the connection is closed selenium stops identifying some elements on the website that I run my test on. I have never had this issue before when running servers on Vultr. I would be grateful for some help! Thanks

Comment: When you quit the Remote Desktop session, it's just like logging off of Windows - anything you have running is stopped. It probably makes more sense to run your script as a service.

Comment: No, it's not. When I log back in, everything is back to where I left it, along with the selenium script that starts working again. Like I said, I never had this problem with Vultr servers which work in the same way.

Comment: Ah, I was going off experience with other servers, not AWS. At any rate, I would still try making it a service and trying to run it outside of your user session.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement it :))